# AngularJS Promise is executed before the data is fetched from Database

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular Promise to execute the functions which are dependent on the data array fetched from the database.

I used resolve and promise to do that as below.

```
function Mainctrl($q,MyService){
    var defer=$q.defer();
    defer.promise
    //The data im receiving in promise is from the resolve "MyService.getAll({ID :ID})"
        .then(function(data){
            $scope.mydata=data;
            $scope.mylength=$scope.mydata.length;
            console.log();
        });
    //This code MyService.getAll({ID :ID}) returns an array from the database, i am using that result array in promise as "data"
    defer.resolve(MyService.getAll({ID :ID}));
}
```

Issue is promise is executed before the data array is populated always shows the lenght as 0. but i i use timeout instead of promise, data array is populated and length is shown correctly.

MyFactory method getAll is

```
app.factory("MyService", function($resource, $http) {
  var resource = $resource("/rest/:ID ", { ID : "@_ID " },
    {
      'create':  { method: 'POST' },
      'getAll':   { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
      'get':    { method: 'GET', isArray: false },
      'update':  { method: 'PUT' },
      'destroy': { method: 'DELETE' }
    }
  );
  return resource;
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that `MyService.getAll` does synchronously return an array? It looks very much like an async method.

Comment: @Bergi: Thanks for the help. it is async only.

Comment: @MohamedHussain Can you show the `MyService.getAll` method? Does it call `$http`?

Comment: @Bergi: I added the factory. updated the question.

Comment: The problem is that you resolve the promise in your synchronous code. If (for some reason) you wanted the code to look like this, `defer.resolve()` should be called inside the `then(function(data){...})` call. See the answer from Chandermani for the most correct solution.

Comment: @Bergi: Thanks For the help. i am getting the following error in my console "Object [object Array] has no method 'then'"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what you have done, but controller does not require to create any defer\promise object.

The code should be in lines of

```
function Mainctrl($scope,MyService){
        MyService.getAll({ID :ID}).then(function(data){
            $scope.mydata=data;
            $scope.mylength=$scope.mydata.length;
            console.log();
        });
}
```

**Update**
Since you service is not returning promise but a resource object the call to `getAll` does not return promise but an array that gets filled later.

```
function Mainctrl($scope,MyService){
            MyService.getAll({ID :ID},function(data){
                $scope.mydata=data;
                $scope.mylength=$scope.mydata.length;
                console.log();
            });
    }
```

Comment: :Thanks For the help.  i am getting the follwoing eror in my console "Object [object Array] has no method 'then'"

Comment: Does the getAll function in "MyService" return a promise?

Comment: @MattyM it does not, it returns a resource.

Comment: @Chandermani Thanks For the help, now it is working. i am new to this angular world. i got confused for the past two days.

Answer (score 1):

According to [docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource), the `getAll` method does return an empty array which will be populated asynchronously with values when they arrive. Ugly design.

```
function Mainctrl($scope,MyService){
    MyService.getAll({ID :ID}).$promise.then(function(data){
        $scope.mydata = data;
        $scope.mylength = data.length;
    });
}
```

Comment: I am getting the following after i implemented in console "TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined"

Comment: Does the array have any additional properties?

Comment: data array is array of javascript object. each object has 6 key value pairs. data=[{key1:val1,...,key6:val6},{},{}..]

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood the docs then. Seems you need to use a callback to `getAll`, without any promises.

Comment: How to do that? right i used timeout and i implemented the functionality i needed from the data array. Is it anyway to do that without modifying the factory?

Comment: A comma. Don't forget the closing parenthesis after the function.

Comment: You and Chandermani patiently helped me lot, now it is working.